# How to extract title from P tag

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```
<p class="mrgn-bttm-0 pop text-center" title="Chance of Precipitation"><small> 30%</small></p>
```

I want to extract "Chance of Precipitation 30%" from the above example p tag. There are actually 14 of these tags, one for each day. I got all the p tags using;

```
f = soup.find('details', {'class':"panel panel-default wxo-fcst"})
```

then I have tried:

```
for i in f:
    print i.find('p')['title']
```

and

```
for i in x.findAll("p"):
    print i.find('p')['title'])
```

but I am getting nowhere. Can someone assist please?

Comment: Try `[p['title'] + p.text.strip() for p in f.findAll('p')]`?

Comment: In example you have class="mrgn-bttm-0 pop text-center" but you're asigning to variable "f" 'class':"panel panel-default wxo-fcst"

Comment: using your suggestion I get "Exception is 'title'". I am trying to scape the data from https://weather.gc.ca/city/pages/ab-52_metric_e.html. f = soup.find('details', {'class':"panel panel-default wxo-fcst"}) gives me all the p takes I want to scrape the title from.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way out:

```
f = soup.find('details', {'class':"panel panel-default wxo-fcst"})
for i in f.find_all('p',{'class':'mrgn-bttm-0 pop text-center'}):
    print i['title']+" "+i.get_text().strip()
```

Output:

```
Chance of Precipitation 
Chance of Precipitation 
Chance of Precipitation 
Chance of Precipitation 
Chance of Precipitation 
Chance of Precipitation 60%
Chance of Precipitation 
Chance of Precipitation 
Chance of Precipitation 
Chance of Precipitation 
Chance of Precipitation 
Chance of Precipitation 60%
```